# Pin numbering of FPC1020AP chip

Tags: packages

I have a single FPC1020AP chip as shown in the picture below. The [datasheet](http://www.shenzhen2u.com/doc/Module/Fingerprint/710-FPC1020_PB3_Product-Specification.pdf) for FPC1020 says there are 19 pins, of which 15 are used. However, I cannot find the datasheet for this exact chip, which says which pad on the chip maps to which pin in the functional description. Thus I presume this must be somewhat standardized. The chip itself seems to have 34 pads and a marking in the corner, I suppose to indicate pad 1.

I contacted the manufacturer, but until now I did not get a response. I am unfamiliar with this package type, but if you would have to guess, which pad is which pin? Or is this blatently obvious and someone can point me to the specification of this package type?

[image]

Comment: I am totally unfamilliar with this package, but by taking a look at the bottom side of the IC on the photo you send. I would say the left bottom corner with the triangle is pin 1 as it is the only indicator.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a different package from the one described in the datasheet - see Fig. 17. You should confirm this with the distributor's FAE or the manufacturer and see if they can supply the correct datasheet. If the distributor and manufacturer can't help, abandon the chip and use another one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a capacitive fingerprint scanner. I've tried to contact the manufacturer as well and did not get any response so I have spent some time to discover how to connect the module.

The pads on the package are organized in a grid with columns numbered from 1 to 7 and rows numbered from A go G.

[image: FPC1020AP package dimensions and pad numbering]

The signals are connected as follows:

[image: FPC1020AP symbol]

where A1 is the pad closest to the "Pin #1 Corner".

The module operates via SPI interface. I've managed to build a test board for the package and communicate with it from NodeMCU/Arduino. You can find more information and corresponding Eagle library in my [blog](https://en.ovcharov.me/2019/12/03/fpc1020-fingerprint-scanner/).